# VB.NET how to simplify block of code and make it reusable

Tags: vb.net, function, linq, class

I have this code that initialize a list with the result of a linq query. On that list I have to try different combinations of letters sobstitution and search for them on the db, if one of the modified versions exists I do stuff (non important for this matter):

```vb
arr_TargheRifiutate = dbCaw.transiti.Where(
    Function(t) (t.dataora >= dataInizio And t.dataora < dataFine) And
    (Not t.autorizzato.HasValue Or t.autorizzato = 0) And
    t.identificativo.Length = 7 And Not t.identificativo.Contains("2365")).ToList
For Each targa In arr_TargheRifiutate
    Dim str_identificativo As String = targa.identificativo
    Dim str_identificativoCG As String = Replace(str_identificativo, "C", "G")
    Dim str_identificativoGC As String = Replace(str_identificativo, "G", "C")
    Dim str_identificativoCD As String = Replace(str_identificativo, "C", "D")
    Dim str_identificativoVW As String = Replace(str_identificativo, "V", "W")
    Dim str_identificativoFH As String = Replace(str_identificativo, "F", "H")
    Dim str_identificativoKX As String = Replace(str_identificativo, "K", "X")
    Dim str_identificativoDO As String = Replace(str_identificativo, "D", "O")
    Dim str_identificativoAE As String = Replace(str_identificativo, "A", "E")

    Dim str_identificativoC1 As String = ReplaceAt(str_identificativo, "C", "G", 0)
    Dim str_identificativoC2 As String = ReplaceAt(str_identificativo, "C", "G", 1)
    Dim str_identificativoG1 As String = ReplaceAt(str_identificativo, "G", "C", 0)
    Dim str_identificativoG2 As String = ReplaceAt(str_identificativo, "G", "C", 1)
    Dim str_identificativoC6 As String = ReplaceAt(str_identificativo, "C", "G", 5)
    Dim str_identificativoC7 As String = ReplaceAt(str_identificativo, "C", "G", 6)
    Dim str_identificativoG6 As String = ReplaceAt(str_identificativo, "G", "C", 5)
    Dim str_identificativoG7 As String = ReplaceAt(str_identificativo, "G", "C", 6)

    Dim targaCorretta As String = ""
    Dim anagrafica As New ANAGRAFICO
    If dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativo) Then
        anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativo).SingleOrDefault
        targaCorretta = str_identificativo
    ElseIf dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoCG) Then
        anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoCG).SingleOrDefault
        targaCorretta = str_identificativoCG
    ElseIf dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoGC) Then
        anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoGC).SingleOrDefault
        targaCorretta = str_identificativoGC
    ElseIf dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoCD) Then
        anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoCD).SingleOrDefault
        targaCorretta = str_identificativoCD
    ElseIf dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoVW) Then
        anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoVW).SingleOrDefault
        targaCorretta = str_identificativoVW
    ElseIf dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoFH) Then
        anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoFH).SingleOrDefault
        targaCorretta = str_identificativoFH
    ElseIf dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoKX) Then
        anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoKX).SingleOrDefault
        targaCorretta = str_identificativoKX
    ElseIf dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoDO) Then
        anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoDO).SingleOrDefault
        targaCorretta = str_identificativoDO
    ElseIf dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoAE) Then
        anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoAE).SingleOrDefault
        targaCorretta = str_identificativoAE
    Else
        If dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoC1) Then
            anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoC1).SingleOrDefault
            targaCorretta = str_identificativoC1
        ElseIf dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoC2) Then
            anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoC2).SingleOrDefault
            targaCorretta = str_identificativoC2
        ElseIf dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoG1) Then
            anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoG1).SingleOrDefault
            targaCorretta = str_identificativoG1
        ElseIf dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoG2) Then
            anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoG2).SingleOrDefault
            targaCorretta = str_identificativoG2
        ElseIf dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoC6) Then
            anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoC6).SingleOrDefault
            targaCorretta = str_identificativoC6
        ElseIf dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoC7) Then
            anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoC7).SingleOrDefault
            targaCorretta = str_identificativoC7
        ElseIf dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoG6) Then
            anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoG6).SingleOrDefault
            targaCorretta = str_identificativoG6
        ElseIf dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Any(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoG7) Then
            anagrafica = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.Where(Function(a) a.CODFISC = str_identificativoG7).SingleOrDefault
            targaCorretta = str_identificativoG7
        End If
    End If
```

I'd like to simplify the code above and make it reusable inside different functions. How can I do it? Is this a case for using classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the exact same thing with 17 different variables (unless I am missing something).
I think the way to go is to replace these string variables by a collection of strings. A `HashSet(Of String)` is the fastest collection for looking up a value. If, however, you are using an O/R-mapper like EF Core, then this does not matter, as the query will be translated to SQL anyway. So, we can also use an array.

Inside your For Each loop you would declare:

```vb
Dim str_identificativo As String = targa.identificativo
Dim identificativi As String() = {
    str_identificativo,
    Replace(str_identificativo, "C", "G"),
    Replace(str_identificativo, "G", "C"),
    Replace(str_identificativo, "C", "D"),
    Replace(str_identificativo, "V", "W"),
    Replace(str_identificativo, "F", "H"),
    Replace(str_identificativo, "K", "X"),
    Replace(str_identificativo, "D", "O"),
    Replace(str_identificativo, "A", "E"),
    ReplaceAt(str_identificativo, "C", "G", 0),
    ReplaceAt(str_identificativo, "C", "G", 1),
    ReplaceAt(str_identificativo, "G", "C", 0),
    ReplaceAt(str_identificativo, "G", "C", 1),
    ReplaceAt(str_identificativo, "C", "G", 5),
    ReplaceAt(str_identificativo, "C", "G", 6),
    ReplaceAt(str_identificativo, "G", "C", 5),
    ReplaceAt(str_identificativo, "G", "C", 6)
}
```

And then you can find the first match with:

```vb
Dim targaCorretta As String = ""
Dim anagrafica As New ANAGRAFICO
Dim found As ANAGRAFICO = dbStart.ANAGRAFICO.FirstOrDefault(
    Function(a) identificativi.Contains(a.CODFISC))
If found IsNot Nothing Then
    anagrafica = found
    targaCorretta = found.CODFISC
End If
```

You could also use `SingleOrDefault` if you prefer.

`SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception if there is more than one element satisfying the condition. `FirstOrDefault` will not throw and is faster than `SingleOrDefault` because it will stop looping as soon as an element is found while the latter will have to loop until the end of the enumeration to test for a possible second candidate.

Comment: Thank you for your time and precise explanation and best practice!